# jquery select outermost div of a nest of selected divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to select a div, but ignore all `divs` selected that are children of a selected div. No `divs` have any other way to identify them other than an `HREF` that I am matching. For example:

```js
outerdiv = $('a[href^="http://bizmate."]').closest('div');
outerdiv.prepend("This was selected")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Won't be selected
  <div>
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
    <div>
      Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      <div>
        Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code selects all the `divs`, including the child. How can I limit it to only select the outermost div that satisfies the condition while ignoring the child `divs` that also satisfy the given condition?

**Edit:**

**Currently, the example would give:**

Won't be selected
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate 
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate 
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate 
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate

**I want the result to be:**

Won't be selected 
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate 
Powered by Bizmate 
Powered by Bizmate 
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select any top level parent, independent of the amount of clusters or their exact structure by filtering out the children based on the amount of links found down the tree :

```js
var link = 'a[href^="http://bizmate."]',

outerdiv = $(link).filter(function() {

    var total = $(this).parents('div:last').find(link).length;

    if (total > 1) {
      var parent = $(this).closest('div').find(link).length;
      if (parent == total) return $(this);
    }
    else return $(this);

}).closest('div');

outerdiv.prepend("This was selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Won't be selected
  <div>
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
    <div>
      Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      <div>
        Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, you're very welcome. It wrecked my brain a bit at first how to put this together but it was quite educational for myself to do so. Interesting question you posted.

Answer (score 3):

Use `has()` and [last()](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

1. `a[href^="http://bizmate."]`: Selects all the anchor elements whose `href` value starts with(^) "http://bizmate.".
2. `:last`: Selects last element from the matched set
3. `closest('div')`: Gets the closest matching ancestor

**Demo:**

```js
$('div > a[href^="http://bizmate.in"]').each(function() {
  $(this).parents('div:has(> a[href^="http://bizmate.in"])')
    .last().addClass('hello');
});
```

```css
.hello > a {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Won't be selected
  <div>
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
    <div>
      Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      <div>
        Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run the code, it seems to select only the very first div. I need it to select the div from the first nest, and the div from the second nest below, the result would look like:
Won't be selected
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate
Powered by Bizmate
Powered by Bizmate
This was selectedPowered by Bizmate

Comment: This works! I will now have to study why it works, haha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the given structure, it's quite efficient so +1 from me. I was likely overthinking it myself although reading the question, it's not an exact answer but will rather always select the first and last link on the entire page instead of getting the outer most link of any cluster present.

Comment: Hmm... looking at it again, it's really not an answer to the question at all. Just a workaround for the current markup. Gave it too much credit so better not edit. ;-)

Comment: Ah, you're right. The answer only worked for the example I gave, but it won't work for a case where I have more than 2 groups of nests.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var x = $(this).closest('div')
   $(x).prepend("This was selected");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the parent div and do the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div>Won't be selected
  <div class="test">
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
    <div>
      Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      <div>
        Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="test">
    Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
outerdiv = $('a[href^="http://bizmate."]').closest('div.test');
$(outerdiv).prepend("This was selected")
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hg989ffp/

Comment: I cannot edit the HTML I am trying to work on, so adding a class or ID won't work in this case. Unless there is some way to add the class with jQuery, I can't use this. Of course, if you can add the class with JavaScript to the outermost 'div' of the nest, that would answer my question.